# <amp-carousel> not working as expected with dynamic data using <amp-list>

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I have my HTML:

```
<amp-list height="400" layout="fixed-height" src="data.json">
   <template type="amp-mustache">
      <amp-carousel height="200" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel">
         <amp-img src="img/{{ imgSrc }}.jpg" layout="fixed" width="100" height="100" alt="{{ productName }}"></amp-img>
      </amp-carousel>
   </template>
</amp-list>
```

Which should display a carousel with the product images I've specified within the `data.json` file. However, if you take a look at my page [here](https://www.perfectimprints.com/amp/product/offering-buckets/), it isn't functioning as I'd expect. I tried removing the dynamic functions and it works as expected, so something with the `<amp-list>` is confusing it. I followed the issues on the AMP Project GitHub: [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/14689), [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10706), and [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/4405#issuecomment-318204399).

Here's what the component **should** look like:

https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-carousel%2Fsource%2F&mode=Responsive

And here's what it looks like currently:

https://www.perfectimprints.com/amp/product/offering-buckets/

Any insights would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They key is to use the amp-list in `single-item` mode and then manually iterate over the different items:

```
<amp-list width="325" height="325" layout="fixed" single-item src="/items.json">
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <amp-carousel type="slides" layout="fill">
      {{#items}}
      <amp-img src="{{src}}" layout="fill" alt="{{alt}}"></amp-img>
      {{/items}}
    </amp-carousel>
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

Another trick is to let the amp-list define the layout and then use the fill layout for carousel and images.

Answer (score 0):

I got some solution for it.

```
{
items: [
        {
        values: [
                    {
                        category:"cate1",
                        image_link: "url1",
                    },
                    {
                        category:"cate1",
                        image_link: "url2",
                    },
                    {
                        category:"cate1",
                        image_link: "url3",
                    },
                    {
                        category:"cate1",
                        image_link: "url4",
                    },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

above json data format we are getting from api.
if you does not has this format data from api then you have to chage to this format only.

```
<amp-list id="list_id" width="350" height="150" layout="flex-item"
                    src="api url">
                    <template type="amp-mustache">
                        <amp-carousel width="350" height="150" layout="fixed" type="carousel" autoplay delay="2000"
                            loop>
                            {{#values}}
                            <div role="text">
                                <amp-img src="{{image_link}}" layout="fixed" width="100" height="100" alt="{{title}}">
                                </amp-img>
                                <p class="category_label">{{category}}</p>
                            </div>
                            {{/values}}
                        </amp-carousel>
                    </template>
                </amp-list>
```

above code for carousel.

[image]

it will display like above.

Thanks

Vishal

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround which you need to try.

`amp-list` expects an items array or object. For `amp-carousel` to work with `amp-list` and `amp-mustache`, you need to structure your response like this.

```
  {"items": [{
    "values": [/*...*/]
```

In your html code do this,

```
<amp-list height="400" layout="fixed-height" src="data.json">
   <template type="amp-mustache">
      <amp-carousel height="400" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel">
       {{#values}}
         <amp-img src="img/{{imgSrc}}.jpg" layout="fixed" width="100" height="100" alt="{{productName}}"></amp-img>
       {{/values}}
      </amp-carousel>
   </template>
</amp-list>
```

If your arrows are disappearing, then you need to add `controls` attribute to amp-carousal.

```
<amp-carousel height="400" layout="fixed-height" type="carousel" controls>
.
.
</amp-carousel>
```